# google structured data testing tool displays question mark character instead of utf-8 characters

Tags: json-ld, structured-data

After testing URL in the google structured data testing tool, I don't know why the question mark character is shown instead of utf-8 characters?
what is wrong? any help really appreciated.
the url is : [link](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=https%3A%2F%2Ftiradsono.com%2Fhypothyroidism%2F)
and the result image:
[image]

The underlying json is:

[image]

Comment: It seems to work fine in the Rich Results Tester which is a more accurate representation on what Google will see.

Answer (score 1):

don't know why, but the structured data tool doesn't understand your farsi. If farsi is an encoded javascript, like `\u0645\u0648\u0633\u0633\u0647` - there is no problem. But if it is written like `علائم تیروئید کم کار` - something wired happens.

Fast and dirty solution: encode all of your structured data content as encoded javascript. In Notepad++ this makes a plugin named HTML Tag - then `ctrl+j`.

Comment: Yes, the previous tester will be set off in short. So the future-proof test tool is the rich results tester.